# Double transclusion with angular 2 and angular material 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-material2

I have two components and I want to transclude the md-hint from the
upper one inside the md-input tag and from there the md-input should
render it.
Right now this doesn't work. Can anyone explain to me how
could I reach the result I want?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-test',
  template: `
    <div>
      <md-input placeholder="Test">
        <ng-content selector="md-hint"></ng-content>
      </md-input>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class MyTest {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <my-test>
        <md-hint>This is my hint</md-hint>
      </my-test>
    </div>
  `,
})
```

[Here is the plunker for it](https://plnkr.co/edit/ePMygDJa33Ev5H85wpNz?p=preview)

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work. I believe it's `<ng-content select="...">` (not `selector`) but I tried in your Plunkr and it doesn't work either. If the hint is the only content of `<my-test>`, you could project it with `<ng-content></ng-content>` with no selector.

Comment: It's not the only content, I need this because I wanted to use md-hint to display errors and set the error value and the hint value independent. when I use md input it works fine, but I built an autocomplete which has a md-input inside, what I want to do is to offer the same worflow for the autocomplete like for the md-input

Comment: I this it doesn't work because angular renders md input before projecting the content inside the md-input tags and at that time the md-input has not content

Comment: Have you managed to fixed this error, came across it myself. So looking for a solution, thanks!

Comment: No I didn't manage, Multiple trasclusion can be done only with ng-template